# get previous years in array using momentjs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

How can I generate a list of array till today? I can't hardcode `[2016,2017,2018]`, because I have to do it every year.

`function (numberOfYearsBack) { // }`

Comment: You don't really need `moment.js` for this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get the current year using [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), and use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a map function to declare and initialize an array with the values you need:

```js
const years = (back) => {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  return Array.from({length: back}, (v, i) => year - back + i + 1);
}

console.log(years(3));
```

Comment: Another option for the return value: `return Array.from({ length: back }, (v, i) => year - back + i + 1);`

Comment: @RobertMennell I like that. Never thought of that approach.

Comment: `Array.from()` has a nice footprint that makes this sort of thing REALLY smooth

Comment: @RobertMennell Yeah, I agree. Updated my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function years(count, startYear){
   const yearList = [];
   const year = startYear || new Date().getFullYear();   
   for(let i = 0; i < count; i+=1 ){
       yearList.push(Number(year)-i)
   }
   return yearList.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
}
console.log(years(10, 2022))
```